# can't call ScrollView self.minimum_height from the builder string

Tags: python, scroll, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am using a builder for a string as a kv file, so I can't call self.minimum_height, as I've seen some people do. How can I set the height inside the string?

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    layoutContent: layoutContent
    FloatLayout:
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id: layoutContent
                cols: 2
                rows: 10
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: 'Goto settings'
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'

'''
```

Comment: If you are talking about the `GridLayout`, you can just use `size_hint_y: None` and  `height: self.minimum_height`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnAnderson . I am getting a recoil animation when I scroll down. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Try setting `effect_cls: 'ScrollEffect'` in your `ScrollView`.